# How to set two time formatters in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, xticks

This chart is built by Excel.
[image]
How can I do the same using matplotlib?

I mean how to add two formatters:

- years
- months.

Now i use something like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.margins(x=0)
ax.plot(list(df['Date']), list(df['Value']), color="g")
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
plt.text(df["Date"].iloc[-1], df["Value"].iloc[-1], df["Value"].iloc[-1])
plt.title(title)
plt.get_current_fig_manager().full_screen_toggle()
plt.grid(axis = 'y')
plt.savefig('pict\\'+sheet.cell_value(row,1).split(',')[0]+'.png', dpi=300, format='png')
#plt.show()
plt.close(fig)
```

It draws:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a secondary axis for the `year` labels, while using the primary for the `month` label. You can generate a secondary axis with something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA
import matplotlib.dates as md

fig = plt.figure()
months = host_subplot(111, axes_class = AA.Axes, figure = fig)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom = 0.1)
years = months.twiny()
```

Then you should move the secondary axis to the bottom with:

```
offset = -20
new_fixed_axis = years.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
years.axis['bottom'] = new_fixed_axis(loc = 'bottom',
                                      axes = years,
                                      offset = (0, offset))
```

Finally you plot and then adjust the primary and secondary axes format with `md.MonthLocator` and `md.YearLocator`. Something like this should be fine:

```
months.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.MonthLocator(interval = 1))
months.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%B'))
months.set_xlim([df['Date'].iloc[0], df['Date'].iloc[-1]])

years.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.YearLocator(interval = 1))
years.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H'))
years.set_xlim([df['Date'].iloc[0], df['Date'].iloc[-1]])
```

Try to check these two answers, it should not be difficult to adapt those codes to your case:

- [primary hours, secondary minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62585041/9214357)
- [primary months, secondary days](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62395155/9214357)