# How to add dimension coordinates instead of regular graphs coordinates in Rectangles in matplotlib.patches.rectangle

Tags: python, matplotlib, coordinates, rectangles, dimensions

[image]
I am plotting multiple rectangles using `matplotlib.patches.Rectangle`. I need to  add dimensions for each. Instead of regular X coordinates of graph i need to mention dimensions of each rectangle. In the given picture I need to show x coordinates at the borders not the standard 250, 500, 750..

```
part1 = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((ip.iloc[i,7], ip.iloc[i,8]), ip.iloc[i,3], ip.iloc[i,4], color =np.random.rand(3)) 
ax.add_patch(part1)
plt.text(ip.iloc[i,7]+(0.5*ip.iloc[i,4]), (ip.iloc[i,8]+(0.5*ip.iloc[i,3])),ip.iloc[i,0],rotation='vertical', color = 'white',fontsize=8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## CASE 1: SINGLE GROUP

If you have a `ip` dataframe with a `'x'` and a `'y'` columns with the coordinates of your rectangles which belong to a single group, you can set your ticks with `ax.set_xticks(ip['x'])` and `ax.set_yticks(ip['y'])`. In this way you will get all ticks, except the last one which you have to include with `max(ip['x']) + ip.iloc[np.argmax(ip['x']), ip.columns.get_loc('width')]` and `max(ip['y']) + ip.iloc[np.argmax(ip['y']), ip.columns.get_loc('height')]`.
With your `ip` dataframe, those columns should be the 8th (`7` python index) and the 9th (`8` python index) ones. Check the code below as a reference.

### Code

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ip = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0, 260, 520, 0, 260, 520],
                   'y': [0, 0, 0, 120, 120, 120],
                   'width': [260, 260, 230, 260, 260, 230],
                   'height': [120, 120, 120, 130, 130, 130],
                   'text': np.random.randint(0, 1000, 6)})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i in range(len(ip)):
    part1 = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((ip.iloc[i,0], ip.iloc[i,1]), ip.iloc[i,2], ip.iloc[i,3], color=np.random.rand(3))
    ax.add_patch(part1)
    plt.text(ip.iloc[i,0]+(0.5*ip.iloc[i,2]), (ip.iloc[i,1]+(0.5*ip.iloc[i,3])), ip.iloc[i,4], rotation='vertical', color='white', fontsize=8)

xticks = list(ip['x'])
xticks.append(max(ip['x']) + ip.iloc[np.argmax(ip['x']), ip.columns.get_loc('width')])
yticks = list(ip['y'])
yticks.append(max(ip['y']) + ip.iloc[np.argmax(ip['y']), ip.columns.get_loc('height')])
ax.set_xticks(xticks)
ax.set_yticks(yticks)

ax.set_xlim([min(ip['x']), max(ip['x']) + ip.iloc[np.argmax(ip['x']), ip.columns.get_loc('width')]])
ax.set_ylim([min(ip['y']), max(ip['y']) + ip.iloc[np.argmax(ip['y']), ip.columns.get_loc('height')]])
plt.show()
```

### Dataframe

```
     x    y  width  height  text
0    0    0    260     120   372
1  260    0    260     120   543
2  520    0    230     120   174
3    0  120    260     130   140
4  260  120    260     130    27
5  520  120    230     130   800
```

### Result

[image]

---

## CASE 2: DOUBLE GRUOP

If you have two different groups of areas, as in your image, one below 300 on y and the other above this threshold, you can duplicate the x axis in order to have the lower ticks on the bottom axis (`ax1`) and the upper ticks on the top axis (`ax2`). Check the code below for reference.
Please, note that here I used a different approach in order to simplify a bit the code and the readability.

### Code

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ip = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0, 260, 520, 0, 260, 520, 0, 250, 500, 0],
                   'y': [0, 0, 0, 120, 120, 120, 300, 300, 300, 410],
                   'width': [260, 260, 230, 260, 260, 230, 200, 170, 150, 250],
                   'height': [120, 120, 120, 130, 130, 130, 110, 110, 110, 120],
                   'text': np.random.randint(0, 1000, 10)})

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twiny()

for i in range(len(ip)):
    part1 = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((ip.iloc[i,0], ip.iloc[i,1]), ip.iloc[i,2], ip.iloc[i,3], color=np.random.rand(3))
    ax1.add_patch(part1)
    ax1.text(ip.iloc[i,0]+(0.5*ip.iloc[i,2]), (ip.iloc[i,1]+(0.5*ip.iloc[i,3])), ip.iloc[i,4], rotation='vertical', color='white', fontsize=8)

lower_ip = ip[ip['y'] < 300]
upper_ip = ip[ip['y'] >= 300]

xticks1 = list(lower_ip['x'] + lower_ip['width']) # select the right-side limit of each lower area
xticks1.extend(lower_ip['x'])                     # add the left-side limit of each lower area
xticks1 = set(xticks1)                            # filter by unique values
xticks1 = list(xticks1)                           # convert back to list
xticks1.sort()                                    # sort in increasing order

xticks2 = list(upper_ip['x'] + upper_ip['width']) # select the right-side limit of each upper area
xticks2.extend(upper_ip['x'])                     # add the left-side limit of each upper area
xticks2 = set(xticks2)                            # filter by unique values
xticks2 = list(xticks2)                           # convert back to list
xticks2.sort()                                    # sort in increasing order

# set equal min value for both axes
if xticks1[0] > xticks2[0]:
    xticks2.append(xticks1[0])
elif xticks1[0] < xticks2[0]:
    xticks1.append(xticks2[0])

# set equal max value for both axes
if xticks1[-1] > xticks2[-1]:
    xticks2.append(xticks1[-1])
elif xticks1[-1] < xticks2[-1]:
    xticks1.append(xticks2[-1])

# set lower and upper x ticks
ax1.set_xticks(xticks1)
ax2.set_xticks(xticks2)

yticks = list(ip['y'] + ip['height']) # select the down-side limit of each area
yticks.extend(ip['y'])                # add the up-side limit of each area
yticks = set(yticks)                  # filter by unique values
yticks = list(yticks)                 # convert back to list
yticks.sort()                         # sort in increasing order
ax1.set_yticks(yticks)                # set y ticks

ax1.set_xlim([min(ip['x']), max(ip['x']) + ip.iloc[np.argmax(ip['x']), ip.columns.get_loc('width')]])
ax1.set_ylim([min(ip['y']), max(ip['y']) + ip.iloc[np.argmax(ip['y']), ip.columns.get_loc('height')]])
plt.show()
```

### Dataframe

```
     x    y  width  height  text
0    0    0    260     120   457
1  260    0    260     120   217
2  520    0    230     120   467
3    0  120    260     130   495
4  260  120    260     130   941
5  520  120    230     130   998
6    0  300    200     110    50
7  250  300    170     110   623
8  500  300    150     110   934
9    0  410    250     120   366
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help. I have a further query. If you refer to my figure, there is are 2 sets of rectangles.. the second set which starts from 300 in the figure. Can we modify the xticks & yticks for them to show X & Y coordinates separately for the second figure?
Hope i am clear with my question? Please help.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent reponses.. It really helped me. But yet again I still have some extra queries. I wanted to label these tow sets differently and in the Y side of the graph. Like naming them as "SET-1" for the first group and "SET-2" for the second group. Is that possible to create 2 different textboxes in the Y-side of the graph?

Comment: Yes, you can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62613876/9214357) as a reference for adding and additional text boxes for the axis label. If you do not manage to adapt that code to your case, I think you should open another question in order to keep this thread as clean as possible, since this further query does not fall into the above question :-)

Comment: Sure Understood. Thank You!!