# How to format Pandas / Matplotlib graph so the x-axis ticks are ONLY hours and minutes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, datetime

I am trying to plot temperature with respect to time data from a csv file.

My goal is to have a graph which shows the temperature data per day.

My problem is the x-axis: I would like to show the time for uniformly and only be in hours and minutes with 15 minute intervals, for example: `00:00`, `00:15`, `00:30`.

The csv is loaded into a pandas dataframe, where I filter the data to be shown based on what day it is, in the code I want only temperature data for 18th day of the month.

Here is the csv data that I am loading in:

```
date,temp,humid
2020-10-17 23:50:02,20.57,87.5
2020-10-17 23:55:02,20.57,87.5
2020-10-18 00:00:02,20.55,87.31
2020-10-18 00:05:02,20.54,87.17
2020-10-18 00:10:02,20.54,87.16
2020-10-18 00:15:02,20.52,87.22
2020-10-18 00:20:02,20.5,87.24
2020-10-18 00:25:02,20.5,87.24
```

here is the python code to make the graph:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("saveData2020.csv")

#make new columns in dataframe so data can be filtered
df["New_Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]).dt.date
df["New_Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]).dt.time
df["New_hrs"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]).dt.hour
df["New_mins"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]).dt.minute
df["day"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['New_Date']).day

#filter the data to be only day 18
ndf = df[df["day"]==18]

#display dataframe in console
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', ndf.shape[0]+1)
print(ndf.head(10))

#plot a graph
ndf.plot(kind='line',x='New_Time',y='temp',color='red')

#edit graph to be sexy
plt.setp(plt.gca().xaxis.get_majorticklabels(),'rotation', 30)
plt.xlabel("time")
plt.ylabel("temp in C")

#show graph with the sexiness edits
plt.show()
```

here is the graph I get:

[image: the plot window]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Answer

First of all, you have to convert `"New Time"` (your x axis) from `str` to `datetime` type with:

```
ndf["New_Time"] = pd.to_datetime(ndf["New_Time"], format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

Then you can simply add this line of code before showing the plot (and import the proper matplotlib library, `matplotlib.dates` as `md`) to tell matplotlib you want only hours and minutes:

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
```

And this line of code to fix the 15 minutes span for the ticks:

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(md.MinuteLocator(byminute = [0, 15, 30, 45]))
```

For more info on x axis time formatting you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62613876/9214357).

### Code

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md

df = pd.read_csv("saveData2020.csv")


#make new columns in dataframe so data can be filtered
df["New_Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]).dt.date
df["New_Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]).dt.time
df["New_hrs"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]).dt.hour
df["New_mins"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]).dt.minute
df["day"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['New_Date']).day

#filter the data to be only day 18
ndf = df[df["day"]==18]
ndf["New_Time"] = pd.to_datetime(ndf["New_Time"], format = "%H:%M:%S")

#display dataframe in console
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', ndf.shape[0]+1)
print(ndf.head(10))

#plot a graph
ndf.plot(kind='line',x='New_Time',y='temp',color='red')

#edit graph to be sexy
plt.setp(plt.gca().xaxis.get_majorticklabels(),'rotation', 30)
plt.xlabel("time")
plt.ylabel("temp in C")

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(md.MinuteLocator(byminute = [0, 15, 30, 45]))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))

#show graph with the sexiness edits
plt.show()
```

### Plot

[image]

### Notes

If you do not need `"New_Date"`, `"New_Time"`, `"New hrs"`, `"New_mins"` and `"day"` columns for other purposes than plotting, you can use a shorter version of the above code, getting rid of those columns and appling the day filter directly on `"date"` column as here:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md

df = pd.read_csv("saveData2020.csv")

# convert date from string to datetime
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

#filter the data to be only day 18
ndf = df[df["date"].dt.day == 18]

#display dataframe in console
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', ndf.shape[0]+1)
print(ndf.head(10))

#plot a graph
ndf.plot(kind='line',x='date',y='temp',color='red')

#edit graph to be sexy
plt.setp(plt.gca().xaxis.get_majorticklabels(),'rotation', 30)
plt.xlabel("time")
plt.ylabel("temp in C")

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(md.MinuteLocator(byminute = [0, 15, 30, 45]))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))

#show graph with the sexiness edits
plt.show()
```

This code will reproduce exactly the same plot as before.

Comment: What would you suggest for adding the humidity data on the same graph? Should i look into subplots? (as you can tell im not very experienced in pandas python or matplotlib :3 ) also what would you suggest to improve in this code? is it ok to use the ndf.plot method? or should just the matplotlib function be used as in: plt.Kool_graph(x_vals, y_vals)?

Comment: Since temperature and humidity are different kinds of data (different quantities with different units) I would suggest to use a [secondary y axis](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/two_scales.html). Usually I prefer to create a `fig` and `ax` objects with `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` and then I plot with `ax.plot(x, y)` method, because I find this way more robust, but one can argue this is a matter of preference. For easy plot you can go with pandas' plot method

Comment: i figured it out, yes i used the "ax1 and ax2" way, your help saved my a$$ thanks again!