# Using DateFormatter resets starting date to 1970

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, matplotlib

I have a dataframe where the index is the first date of each month and the `size` column is the frequency for that month, e.g.

[image: a table showing a list of 1st of the month dates and a frequency]

Using `.index` on the dataframe confirms the type of the index is `DatetimeIndex`:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2006-12-01', ...],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='created_at_month', length=175, freq=None)
```

Using `.plot()` on the DataFrame I can produce a line graph per month:

[image]

However, it only lists every other year on the x axis, and I'd like it to list each year on the axis.

I would expect to be able to do

```py
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator(1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
```

However this doesn't output any labels at all.

If I add a minor formatter (`ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d %m %Y'))`), I get this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here to cause the dates to change?

The relevant versions are:

- Matplotlib: 3.3.4
- Pandas: 1.2.4
- Python: 3.8.8

Comment: Lemme guess you're trying to display all years on the X axis?

Comment: Yeah I want all the years labelled as major ticks, and then ideally all the months as minor ticks but I want to get years working first

Comment: Would you mind sharing a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: See https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/api/date_demo.html

Comment: Here is a minimal example, I'll check if the first answer resolves this issue https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1U7jySEmK03SDPtC5Z1G9wRY7SBxAiXUN?usp=sharing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64356273/9214357), for some reason `pandas`'s plot shows this issue.
You can overcome this issue by replacing `pandas`' plot with `matplotlib.pyplot.plot`.
You can take [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62613876/9214357) as a reference for 2 datetime ticks on x axis (month and year, or month and day, or day and hour, as you need), using two different axis in palce of minor and major ticks.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'created_at_month': pd.date_range(start = '2006-12-01', end = '2020-12-01', freq = 'MS')})
df['size'] = np.random.randint(0, 200, len(df))
df = df.set_index('created_at_month')


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(df.index, df['size'])

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator(base = 1, month = 1, day = 1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How is this still a problem 2 years later?

Comment: 3 years later...

Answer (score 0):

This is still a problem, a quick workaround is:

x_labels = [date.strftime('%d.%m') for date in df_data.index]
ax.set_xticklabels(x_labels, rotation=45)