# time as x-axis for non-continuous time (as cftime.DatetimeProlepticGregorian)

Tags: matplotlib, time-series, python-datetime, line-plot, pandas-timeindex

I need to plot just year on x-axis.
My time array looks like

```
array([cftime.DatetimeProlepticGregorian(2002, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=True),
       cftime.DatetimeProlepticGregorian(2002, 8, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=True),
       cftime.DatetimeProlepticGregorian(2002, 8, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=True),
       ...,
       cftime.DatetimeProlepticGregorian(2022, 10, 29, 0, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=True),
       cftime.DatetimeProlepticGregorian(2022, 10, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=True),
       cftime.DatetimeProlepticGregorian(2022, 10, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=True)],
      dtype=object)
```

When I plot:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": date_time.astype(str),
                   "Value": values})
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(15,3))
#df.Date.astype(str)
plt.set_loglevel('WARNING')
ax.plot(df.Date, df.Value, linestyle='dotted')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(YearLocator(1, month=1, day=5))  # Tick locator #, day=10
```

I get
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQth0.png)

But, I just want years on x-axis.

What I tried was,
converting the datetime to pandas index, then to numeric

```
year = pd.DatetimeIndex(date_time).year
```

```
dt = pd.to_numeric(year)
```

and I get

[image]

This happening because, my data uses only 3 months as a continuous array and not the entire year, but I wanted those 3 months to look continuous annually.
That is, as the data is non-continuous I can't set/use the pd.date_range(start = '2002-08-01', end = '2022-08-23', freq = 'D'), the length of the array changes to 7397, whereas mine is 1900 (As it uses only 3 months data). How can I customize the pandas time-index to just Aug-Sep-Oct and loop over to get a continuous array plot?

Altogether, I wanted the plot to look like a daily one in the top image whilst having the x-axis as only years, so that it can accommodate more years to visualize.

Any help will be highly appreciated
Many thanks

Update 1 ::::
After doing what @matt suggested, it answers the year on x-axis but as the data has breaks and uses only few months the image looks like [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGojG.png)

Answer (score 0):

As in, e.g., [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69102135/1862861), I think all you need to change is to switch

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(YearLocator(1, month=1, day=5))
```

to be:

```
from matplotlib.dates import YearLocator, DateFormatter

...

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(YearLocator(1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%Y"))
```

i.e., just specify the year locator to be every year and the formatting of the date to only show the year.

*Update*:

If there's a problem of the date's starting at 1970 in the plot, then you can wrap the `date_time.astype(str)` in a [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), e.g.,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Date": pd.to_datetime(date_time.astype(str)),
        "Value": values,
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the response @matt. I tried this (ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(YearLocator(1))) earlier too and get the plot as  1970-1975 as years. But my data has years starting from 2002-2022, for Aug-Sep-Oct months

Comment: As the data is non-continuous I cant set the ```pd.date_range(start = '2002-08-01', end = '2022-08-23', freq = 'D')```, the length of the array changes to 7397, whereas mine is 1900. How can I customize just Aug-Sep-o?

Comment: When you create the DataFrame, if you wrap `date_time.astype(str)` in a `pd.to_datetime()`, it should fix the issue of the data starting at 1970, e.g., `df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": pd.to_datetime(date_time.astype(str)), "Value": values})`.

Comment: Thanks @matt for the solution, but it is again showing up at monthly scale, not like a continuous array. I'll edit in the question part as I'm unable to post the figure here